# NodeJs: fs.unlink does not delete file [VS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio

I am aware this isn't the first post about fs.unlink not working, but I'm very new to both Visual Studio and Node Js.

I want to delete a file in the working folder, I got an error and the file is not deleted.

Here is what I tried:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.unlink('test1.txt');
```

PS: I installed the necessary Node Js components in VS.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio, or Visual Studio Code?  They are very different products.  You will get different answers depending on that.

Comment: @dvsoukup Hi! thank you for responding. I created a new Javascript file inside VS and wrote the code there. Does that make it VS code?

Comment: It's like a modern-day Abbott and Costello sketch... Visual Studio Code is the name of an IDE application, which is different from the application that's just called Visual Studio. Does your application call itself Visual Studio Code (in the title bar, menu bar, or icon)? Or does it just call itself Visual Studio?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Hi! I doubt it's Visual Studio Code. I checked and it's: Microsoft Visual Studio/Visual Studio 2017/Visual Studio Community (<I chose the last title in Microsoft's download page).

Comment: It doesn’t matter what ide is being used. It’s Node....

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree. I have a quick question regarding that. Is the quickest and best way to run through node to type [node filename] in cmd prompt inside Visual Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as the code goes, you're not invoking `fs.unlink` properly.  For starters, it's asynchronous.  You will need to provide it a callback.  See example here:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback

Secondly, you need to provide it the full file path, not just the name of the file... ie:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.unlink('C:\path\to\my\file\test1.txt', (err) => {});
```

You can also supply it with the variable `__dirname` to utilize your current working directory from wherever you invoke node against the script.  Thus, that would look something like:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');

fs.unlink(path.join(__dirname, 'test1.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('test1.txt was deleted');
});
```

Currently, you can also invoke it synchronously using it's single parameter signature... thus you'd provide only the dir path:

```
fs.unlinkSync('C:\\path\\to\\my\\file\\test1.txt');
```

But, this is ill-advised as it will be blocking.  I'd only use the "sync" variant during some application bootstrapping process, where it'd be invoked only one time or so, at startup.  Try to fight the urge of it being "easier" to use and understand, and instead get yourself to understand asynchronous logic.

Comment: Thanks @dvsoukup for the link. So the callback would be handling the error. I did modify the code following this method, and I got this error: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'path\test1.txt']

Comment: Does that path exist on your computer?  I couldn't tell you.  That error is thrown because the file/directory doesn't exist (hence the error description...).  Pass in the full path to the file.

Comment: Yes, I pasted it from the folder and checked spaces and file name. Strange!

Comment: the '\' is an escape character.  So you probably need to use double slashes... like so: 'path\\to\\file\theFile.txt'.  It's kind of a hassle as you can see, which is why I'd suggest you use that option to supply the __dirname variable, and concat it with path.join.

Comment: Is this how you define a variable:
let __dirname = require('C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\node intro\\test1.txt');

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname.
It's just a global variable available within nodejs during runtime.  You don't need to define it anywhere.  Just use it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! 

[test1.txt was deleted].
I better read more about Node Js docs. Btw I think you're supposed to close the bracket in 
(__dirname, 'test1.txt'), 
Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you are.  I just wrote all that free hand though, and missed fully closing it.  Glad you caught it.

Comment: @dvsoukup maybe update the answer with the closing bracket for us noobs? I tried but it requires 6 chars just to add a ")". Is it any different to edit as the OP?